# R merge back List after computation

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr

I am having trouble with a simple problem and I can't find a simple solution to it. (This question is probably a `duplicate` but I can't find it!)

What I need is to `merge` back a list to its original list after a computation.

I need to `merge` because the computation I am doing is too complicated to `apply` them directly to the list. So, I have to do it separately and somehow to put it back to the original dataset. (I can't use `mutate` directly here because of this problem).

Because I can't reproduce my data, I will use `mtcars` to demonstrate my problem.

I have an original list and I am applying a computation to it (it doesn't matter which one), so for example :

```
library(dplyr) 
library(purr)
```

My original dataset is a list

```
dt = mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  split(.$gear)
```

Then, on this list, I do a computation, for example :

```
dt %>% 
  map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp)))
```

And I am ending up with a `list`.

The (real) structure of my data end up looking like this

```
$`3`
   gear cluster
1     3   326.3

$`4`
    gear cluster
 1     4   123
```

and so on. What I need is simply to `merge back` this list to the original list. 
How can I do this ?

What I need (**output wanted**) is to end up with (it's difficult to reproduce here) my original `list` and the `merged` computed values.

Something like

```
$`3`

     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb cluster 
1   21.4     6 258.0   110  3.08 3.215 19.44     1     0     3     1  XXX
2   18.7     8 360.0   175  3.15 3.440 17.02     0     0     3     2  XXX
3   18.1     6 225.0   105  2.76 3.460 20.22     1     0     3     1  XXX
4   14.3     8 360.0   245  3.21 3.570 15.84     0     0     3     4  XXX
```

and so on for all the lists (df)

I emphasise again that **my original dataset is a list not a data.frame**. What I need is to merge `lists`, not `data.frame`.

I thought of something like

```
dt = mtcars %>% # my data is a list
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  split(.$gear)

fmerge = function(x) x %>% lapply(dt, ., by = 'gear')

dt %>% 
  map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp))) %>% 
  lapply(fmerge)
```

or

```
dt %>% 
  map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp))) %>% 
  join_all(dt, ., by = 'gear')
```

But it doesn't work well.

Any clue ?

Comment: If that is the case, my first solution should work

Comment: I don't understand how you can use `summarise` within `map` but your situation is too complicated for `mutate` within `map`.  If you replaced `summarise` with `mutate` inside `map` then you wouldn't 't have to join later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `bind_rows` to rbind the `list` elements and then do a `right_join` or `left_join`

```
mtcars %>% 
   group_by(gear) %>% 
   split(.$gear) %>% 
   map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp))) %>%
   bind_rows() %>%
   right_join(., mtcars, by = "gear")
```

---

However, this can be done without the `split/map/bind_rows/right_join` by just creating the 'cluster' with `mutate` after we `group_by` 'gear'

```
mtcars %>% 
     group_by(gear) %>%
     mutate(cluster = mean(disp))
```

However, we assume that this simplified process may not work in the OP's original dataset.

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments, we can use `map2` to do the `left_join` for corresponding elements of `list`

```
dt %>%
    map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp))) %>% 
    map2(dt, ., left_join, by = "gear")
```

Or if we need a single `data.frame`, then use `map2df`

```
dt %>%
    map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp))) %>% 
    map2_df(dt, ., left_join, by = "gear")
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution but slow because of the `loop`

Store the computation in a 'list`

```
computation = dt %>% map(~summarise(., cluster = mean(disp)))
```

Then loop through both `list`

```
for(i in 1:length(dt)){
  dt[[i]] = merge(dt[[i]], computation[[i]], by = 'gear')
}
```

to get

```
$`3`
   gear  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am carb cluster
1     3 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    1   326.3
2     3 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    2   326.3
3     3 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    1   326.3
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make use of the interesting things you can do with `nest()` from the tidyr package (and then `unnest()`) as follows:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% 
  nest(-gear) %>% 
  mutate(cluster = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.$disp))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 32 × 12
#>     gear  cluster   mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am
#>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1      4 123.0167  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.620 16.46     0     1
#> 2      4 123.0167  21.0     6 160.0   110  3.90 2.875 17.02     0     1
#> 3      4 123.0167  22.8     4 108.0    93  3.85 2.320 18.61     1     1
#> 4      4 123.0167  24.4     4 146.7    62  3.69 3.190 20.00     1     0
#> 5      4 123.0167  22.8     4 140.8    95  3.92 3.150 22.90     1     0
#> 6      4 123.0167  19.2     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.30     1     0
#> 7      4 123.0167  17.8     6 167.6   123  3.92 3.440 18.90     1     0
#> 8      4 123.0167  32.4     4  78.7    66  4.08 2.200 19.47     1     1
#> 9      4 123.0167  30.4     4  75.7    52  4.93 1.615 18.52     1     1
#> 10     4 123.0167  33.9     4  71.1    65  4.22 1.835 19.90     1     1
#> # ... with 22 more rows, and 1 more variables: carb <dbl>
```

If you run the first two, then three, lines of this pipe, you'll see that you have a column of data sets that correspond to the groups in your data. This lets you do some really complex things without splitting the data into separate lists.

For example, the following runs a regression analysis on the data for each gear (again, trying running the first 2, then 3, etc, lines of the pipe to understand how it's working), then plots the results:

```
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  nest(-gear) %>% 
  mutate(fits = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp, .)),
         predicted = map(fits, augment)) %>% 
  unnest(predicted) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, .fitted)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(. ~ gear)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately I MUST work on `lists`, I can't apply the computation on a dataframe.